# The enableOutputCache parameter is not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm trying to block IE from caching my webpage.
After reading some question here I found that there are two solutions:

adding

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
```

to the each controller
or add this to `web.config`

```
<caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
</caching>
```

I decided to go the second way.
After putting it to my config file:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <caching>
       <outputCacheSettings enableOutputCache="false" />
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

the enableOutputCache paremeter is underlined with message: `"The enableOutputCache parameter is not allowed"`
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is syntax error.

This should be:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <caching>
      <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

If you want to know how to use `outputCacheSettings` you can find the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228270(v=vs.85).aspx).